# validate nested json schema required property

Tags: python, json

I have nested json schema like below , how to define the required properties for same ?
Let's say i need to define required property for "version" which is under "baseline". Since i have version also under "pattern", so just defining "baseline" as required will work ? "baseline is static text but "version" under "baseline" is something i want to make as required field.

```
    "versions":{
      "type":"object",
       "properties":{
         "pattern":{
            "version":{
              "type": string
               "description": string
           }
        },
       "baseline":{
            "version":{
              "type": string
               "description": string 
        } 
      }
    },
    "required":[
       "baseline"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and you need to take the version

```
f = open(r'data.json', encoding='utf-8')
data = json.load(f)
for v in data:
version = v['baseline']['version']
```

Comment: No. When defining schema version , how to define required property for baseline->version

Comment: @Bokambo, what will be if u just try : "required": ["version"] ?
The property pattern->version is not marked as required, so it becomes optional

Comment: @ I also have version property under pattern as well, how it will know which one to make as required  , baseline or pattern -> version?

Comment: Well, so there is no direct way to specify different required properties for two nested properties with the same name in different parts of the schema. To do what you want you need to handle this logic outside the schema itself, such as during data validation or processing. For example, you can use jsonschema